# Simple Calculator in C issue

Tags: c

I tried to create a simple calculator in C, but when i started it with all the operations the results is 0, the code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Author: Ermanno Oliveri
Date: 14/11/2021
Description: Simple Calculator
*/

int main(){

    float n1, n2, ris;
    int choice;

    n1 = 0;
    n2 = 0;
    ris = 0;
    choice = 0;

    printf("Insert the first Number: \n");
    scanf("%f", &n1);

    printf("Insert the second Number: \n");
    scanf("%f", &n2);

    printf("enter 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication and 4 for division \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);


    switch (choice){
    case 1:
        ris = n1 + n2;
        printf("\nThe result is: %f", &ris);
        break;

    case 2:
        ris = n1 - n2;
        printf("\nThe result is: %f", &ris);
        break;

    case 3:
        ris = n1 * n2;
        printf("\nThe result is: %f", &ris);
        break;

    case 4:
        if (n2 == 0){
            printf("Impossible division");
            }

            else {
                ris = n1 / n2;
                printf("\nThe result is: %f", &ris);
            }

            break;

    default:
        printf("VALUE NOT VALID");
    }
}
```

I also tried to execute some parts of the code individually, also trying the scanf but the result is always the same.

Since I am a beginner I could not find the problem.

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `printf` should not be a pointer, it should just be `ris` without the `&`.  A good compiler will warn you about this so make sure compiler warnings are enabled and you are looking at them.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove & from printf

```
printf("\nThe result is: %f",ris);
```

modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Author: Ermanno Oliveri
Date: 14/11/2021
Description: Simple Calculator
*/

int main(){

    float n1, n2, ris;
    int choice;

    n1 = 0;
    n2 = 0;
    ris = 0;
    choice = 0;

    printf("Insert the first Number: \n");
    scanf("%f", &n1);

    printf("Insert the second Number: \n");
    scanf("%f", &n2);

    printf("enter 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication and 4 for division \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);


    switch (choice){
    case 1:
        ris = n1 + n2;
        printf("\nThe result is: %f", ris);
        break;

    case 2:
        ris = n1 - n2;
        printf("\nThe result is: %f", ris);
        break;

    case 3:
        ris = n1 * n2;
        printf("\nThe result is: %f", ris);
        break;

    case 4:
        if (n2 == 0){
            printf("Impossible division");
            }

            else {
                ris = n1 / n2;
                printf("\nThe result is: %f", ris);
            }

            break;

    default:
        printf("VALUE NOT VALID");
    }
}
```